# Azure git deployment failure

Tags: git, azure, deployment, bitbucket, azure-deployment

I have a couple of azure web apps deployed from bitbucket.
It was all working fine and never had any problems at all.
Since my last commit the azure deployment now fails with the following error:

```
Command: deploy.cmd

Installing Kudu Sync

D:\local\AppData\npm\kudusync -> D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\kudusync\bin\kudusync

kudusync@0.2.3 D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\kudusync

├── commander@2.6.0

├── q@1.1.2

└── minimatch@2.0.1 (brace-expansion@1.1.0)

Test

'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Handling .NET Web Application deployment.

operable program or batch file.

An error has occured during web site deployment.
```

Usually when there's a deployment error caused by the code I can get to the root cause by examining the error but this time it seems quite unrelated.

Anyone had a similar problem before?

Thanks

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem, is the deploy script outdated?

Comment: I was going through the deploy script right now , might add a few "echo" to print out the variables and see if anything changed.

Comment: I think I found it... the MSBUILDPATH variable value is now without quotes which ends up in d:\program files etc..... , just added quotes around the var name in the deploy script. deploying now and it didn't break as quickly as it was... will let you know.

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: Thx! Worked for me too!

Comment: Thanks, it works! ;)

Comment: Have you experienced really slow deployment after this? It takes ages until it gets through the "running deployment command..." now.

Comment: I did notice it, not all the time though. Sometimes it was as fast as before the change, sometimes it took almost 10mins. not sure whether it's related though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. Going through the deploy.cmd script I added a few "echo" to check the variables values and I noticed that the `MSBUILD_PATH` variable value was D:\Program Files\etc.... and when the script runs there are no quotes around it, hence why the D:\Program error. I added the quotes around it (`"%MSBUILD_PATH%"`) and it's now working fine again.